# Synergy Not Switching monitors correctly using dual monitors on host and client

Tags: synergy

I have recently created a 2x2 monitor setup where the top 2 monitors are my work MacOs laptop, and the bottom 2 monitors are my personal Windows10 desktop. I've set up to share keyboard and mouse between the 2 machines with Synergy (I believe 1 basic). It's all working well now besides 1 small issue. If I want to move my mouse from the desktop (server) to the laptop (client), it HAS to be done through the top of the right monitor, if I go to any spot on the top of the left monitor it doesn't move up. Everything else is working, and even when I move my mouse to the bottom of the top left monitor (laptop) it moves down to the bottom left monitor of the desktop with no issue.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you are doing anything wrong, synergy has many quirks. Two things come to mind:

1. Ensure monitors are properly arranged in both Windows and Mac display properties. Also if possible set the same (left or right) as the **main** one. Where does the laptop screen come in this 2x2 setup ?
2. If 1. doesn't help you might be able to fix it by creating a custom server and or client configuration file: https://symless.com/help-articles/creating-text-config-files